# How to replace strings after underscore in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a string `1:132464_A/T`, in R how can I replace the partial string after underscore `_` with another string? Namely replace `A/T` with `ABC` in this case. The output would be `1:132464_ABC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative with `sub` and `gsub`: (Replace everything from XXXX_A/T with XXXX_ABC)

```
str <- "1:132464_A/T"
sub('\\_.*', '_ABC', str)
```

**OR**

```
gsub("\\_.*","_ABC",str)
```

Output:

```
[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sub`, match the `_` followed by characters (`.*`), replace it with `_` and the string to replace 'BC'

```
sub("_A.*", "_ABC", str1)
#[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

---

Or if we the 'A' changes as well, then capture as a group (`(_.)` - underscore followed by any character `.`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group along with the replacement string

```
sub("(_.).*", "\\1BC", str1)
#[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

---

Or using regex lookarounds to capture the character after a `_` and replace with the backreference of the captured group

```
sub("(?<=_)(.).*", "\\1BC", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

---

Or using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(str1, "_A.*", "_ABC")
#[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

Or using `stri_replace` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace(str1, regex = "_A.*", "_ABC")
#[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

---

Or split the string at `_` and then `paste` after extracting the first element

```
paste0(strsplit(str1, "_")[[1]][1], "_ABC")
#[1] "1:132464_ABC"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "1:132464_A/T"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. What's the difference between sub and gsub?

Comment: @DavidZ `g` means `global` substitution.  Here, we need only a single occurrence to subsitute,  Let's say you wanted to replace every '4' with 'r', then `gsub('4', 'r', str1)` while `sub('4', '4', str1)` replace only the first occurence

Comment: It seems replaced the underscore as well but I wanted to keep it

Comment: Then use the capturing groups example which preserves whatever is contained in the capturing group